# Readers writers problem concurrent Java

Tags: java, concurrency, readerwriterlock

This is an implementation of readers writers, i.e. many readers can read but only one writer can write at any one time.  Does this work as expected?

```
public class ReadersWriters extends Thread{

static int num_readers = 0;
static int writing = 0;

public void read_start() throws InterruptedException {         

    synchronized(this.getClass()) {
        while(writing == 1) wait();
        num_readers++;
    }        
}

public void read_end() {
    synchronized(this.getClass()) {
        if(--num_readers == 0) notifyAll();
    }
}

public void write_start() throws InterruptedException{

    synchronized(this.getClass()) {
        while(num_readers > 0) wait();
        writing = 1;
    } 
}

public void write_end() {
    this.getClass().notifyAll();
}
}
```

Also is this implementation any different from declaring each method

```
public static synchronized read_start()
```

for example?

Thanks

Comment: in my opinion you should avoid waiting/notifying on an object that is publicly available, as this.class or this is. This allows for roque code screwing up your synchronization. The synchronizing object should be a private field of this class.

Comment: Is this homework? If not @Alex Gitelman's answer should likely be accepted.

Comment: > Does this work as expected? (a) what do you expect?
(b) what does it do?
(c) is there a difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - you're implicitly calling `this.wait()`, despite not having synchronized on `this`, but instead on the class. Likewise you're calling `this.notifyAll()` in `read_end`. My suggestions:

- *Don't* extend `Thread` - you're not specializing the thread at all.
- *Don't* use static variables like this from instance members; it makes it *look* like there's state on a per-object basis, but actually there isn't. Personally I'd just use instance variables.
- *Don't* use underscores in names - the conventional Java names would be `numReaders`, `readEnd` (or better, `endRead`) etc.
- *Don't* synchronize on either `this` or the class if you can help it. Personally I prefer to have a `private final Object` variable to lock on (and wait etc). That way you know that *only your code* can be synchronizing on it, which makes it easier to reason about.
- You never set `writing` to 0. Any reason for using an integer instead of a `boolean` in the first place?

Of course, it's better to use the classes in the framework for this if at all possible - but I'm hoping you're really writing this to understand threading better.

Comment: @Ferguzz: No - you're still not setting `writing` to 0 (in `write_end`) and it's still confusing to make *instance* methods completely regardless of their instance (other than to get the class). See my list of bullet points to fix.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve your goal in much simpler way by using

```
java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock
```

Just grab java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock when you start reading and java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock when you start writing.

This class is intended exactly for that - allow multiple readers that are mutually exclusive with single writer.

Answer (score 2):

Your particular implementation of `read_start` is not equivalent to simply declaring the method `synchronized`. As was noted by J. Skeed, you need to call `notify` (and `wait`) on the object you are `synchronize`-ing with. You cannot use an unrelated object (here: the class) for this. And using the `synchronized` modified on a method does not make the method implicitly call `wait` or anything like that.

There is, BTW., an implementation of read/write locks, which ships with the core JDK: [`java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html). Using that one, your code might look like the following instead:

```
class Resource {
    private final ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private final Lock rlock = lock.readLock();
    private final Lock wlock = lock.writeLock();

    void read() { ... /* caller has to hold the read lock */ ... }
    void write() { ... /* caller has to hold the write lock */ ... }

    Lock readLock() { return rlock; }
    Lock writeLock() { return wlock; }
}
```

Usage

```
final Resource r = ...;

r.readLock().lock();
try {
    r.read();
} finally {
    r.unlock();
}
```

and similar for the write operation.

Answer (score 0):

The example code synchronizes on `this.getClass()`, which will return the same `Class` object for multiple instances of `ReadersWriters` in the same class loader. If multiple instances of `ReadersWriters` exist, even though you have multiple threads, there will be contention for this shared lock. This would be similar to adding the `static` keyword to a private lock field (as Jon Skeet suggested) and would likely lead to worse performance than synchronizing on `this` or a private lock object. More specifically, one thread which is reading would be blocking another thread which is writing, and this is likely undesirable.

Comment: that is the required behaviour.  Either one thread can write on its own. or many threads can read when no thread is writing.