# What java.util.concurrent classes would allow me to organize my reads/writes?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

Let's say I have some resources that I want to synchronize access to. Most of these accesses are read only. I'd like to allow as many read only accesses at a time as the system can handle. But, I'd like the ability to stop the reading, make some writes, then allow reading again.

So the read threads might look like this

```
Resource r = null;
readLock.acquire();
r = resources.get();
readLock.release();
```

Any number of threads could do this at the same time, that wouldn't be a problem.

The write threads would look like this:

```
readLock.acquireOnlyMe(); // waits for all other threads to relase
                          // all other threads block when they try to acquire
r = resources.get();
r.setData(data);
readLock.release();
```

Right now, I'm using a `ReentrantLock` that serves as both read and write. But obviously this is causing reads to work sequentially when I'd rather they work simultaneously.

What can I do to solve this problem?

It appears this is [known as the readers-writers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writer_lock), and the wiki entry lists some C implementations, but none for Java.

Edit: I'm open to any Java library that will get the job done. The title says java.util.concurrent because it seems most likely that the answer will lie there.

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6089967/248082) could be your answer.

Comment: "the wiki entry lists some C implementations, but none for Java" -- what about the ReadWriteLock that it mentions was introduced in Java 5?

Comment: That appears to be exactly what I'm looking for. I didn't realize there was a subpackage there. Excellent!

Comment: @yshavit Oh so it does. Wow, I feel like a real winner!

Comment: Btw, make sure you understand fairness -- it's very important in a read-write lock. You probably want the lock to be fair, or your writers could very easily get starved.

Comment: Yeah my current implementation is fair, I would have my other one fair too. It really has to be fair, because the main writer is a daemon process.

Comment: @yshavit your first comment should be an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to limit the writer threads to one, then a ReentrantReadWriteLock would be your man.

For more than one - you probably want to lock your writers using a Semaphore. I recommend basing the initial permit count on the number of cores - probably cores+1.